# FCMPlugin is not defined in Ionic 3

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently building a push notification application using Ionic 3, Cordova and Firebase, I found online resources of how to build the application in the following link: http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-sending-push-notifications-to-specific-devices-part-1/, I was able to build the app.apk and install it in my mobile device for android. The application seems to function normally in my device. I have a problem though, when I type Ionic serve in my cmd I get the following error, "FCMPlugin is not defined", I try different approaches but I wasn’t able to find a solution, I am also quite new to ionic and I don’t know if I am doing anything wrong, did anyone face similar problems?, how can I fix this?

I declare it in my app.compoment.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';




declare var FCMPlugin;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {



FCMPlugin.getToken(
  (t) => {
    console.log(t);
  },
  (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }
);

FCMPlugin.onNotification(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }
);

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

and in my home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';


import firebase from 'firebase';

declare var FCMPlugin;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  firestore = firebase.database().ref('/pushtokens');
  firemsg = firebase.database().ref('/messages');
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.tokensetup().then((token) => {
      this.storetoken(token);
    })
  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
    FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }else{
      //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }
    });

FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token){
    alert( token );
});    
  }

  tokensetup() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token){
    resolve(token);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
});
    })
    return promise;
  }

  storetoken(t) {
    this.afd.list(this.firestore).push({
      uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      devtoken: t

    }).then(() => {
      alert('Token stored');
      })

    this.afd.list(this.firemsg).push({
      sendername: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
      message: 'hello'
    }).then(() => {
      alert('Message stored');
      })
}

}
```

Thanks in Regards

Comment: do this.FCMplugin instead of FCMPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work on a browser as it requires Cordova so you need to always check for either the platform.is('cordova') method or you can simply use typeof

```
if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
 .....        //then execute FCM methods 
}
```

Or

```
If(typeof FCM != typeof 'undefined'){
 .... //only then perform FCM operations 
}
```